# How to add animation in spinner drop down menu list in android?

Tags: android, animation, spinner

I can't found any solution for animated spinner. I want to translate spinner list from bottom like dialog box.

Please help me.

Comment: Change the spinner mode to dropdown

Comment: how exactly you want to animate it? Show it somehow.

Comment: i want to display dropdown list from bottom of the screen.

Comment: mode is already set to dropdown